# Zendesk API to get password expiration time and password changed time of user

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api, zendesk-app, zendesk-sdk

Is there any Oauth Zendesk api, to retrive the org password expiration time and password changed time of org user

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing this answer, no support api end-point exposes this information.